# .torrentファイルの中身を確認する方法はありますか？（開く方法ではありません）

Tags: linux, unix

.torrentファイルの中身を確認する方法はありますか？（開く方法ではありません）

Answer (score 1):

Macであれば、[Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com/download/) の `transmission-show` コマンドで確認できます。

## インストール

※ [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) が必要です。

```
brew install transmission
```

## 確認

```
$ transmission-show amd64cd-5.1.2.iso.torrent
Name: amd64cd-5.1.2.iso
File: amd64cd-5.1.2.iso.torrent

GENERAL

  Name: amd64cd-5.1.2.iso
  Hash: e30c05f2330ba4869eefb90bf5978a505303b235
  Created by: 
  Created on: Sun Feb  5 01:31:29 2012
  Piece Count: 967
  Piece Size: 256.0 KiB
  Total Size: 253.3 MB
  Privacy: Public torrent

TRACKERS

  Tier #1
  http://tracker.netbsd.org:6969/announce

FILES

  amd64cd-5.1.2.iso (253.3 MB)
```

#### 参考

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/is-there-a-tool-to-view-a-torrent-file